# about c++ cast question

Tags: c++, type-conversion, typecast-operator

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int int_sorter( const void *first_arg, const void *second_arg )
{
    int first = *(int*)first_arg;
    int second = *(int*)second_arg;
    if ( first < second )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( first == second )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In this code, what does this line mean?

```
int first = *(int*)first_arg;
```

I thinks it's typecasting. But, from

> a pointer to int
>   to a 
>   pointer to int

little confused here.
Thanks

?

Comment: It's like reinterpret_cast, you are dereferencing the pointer to get an int.

Comment: `stdlib.h` is deprecated in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first_arg is declared as a void*, so the code is casting from void* to int*, then it de-references the pointer to get the value pointed from it. That code is equal to this one:

```
int first = *((int*) first_arg);
```

and, if it is still not clear:

```
int *p = (int *) first_arg;
int first = *p;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is casting a void pointer to a integer pointer and then dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about it in steps.

```
void *vptr = first_arg;
int *iptr = (int *)first_arg; // cast void* => int*
int i = *iptr; // dereference int* => int
```

So, you're specifying the type of data the pointer points to, and then dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int first = *(int*)first_arg;
```

It's the same as:

```
int* ptr_to_int = (int*)first_arg;
int first = *ptr_to_int;
```

That first line does 2 things: it casts the void pointer to an `int*` **and** access that memory location to retrieve the value that's there.

Answer (score 0):

There are already many answers to your question, this is more like a comment, something that you will inevitably learn in your quest on mastering C and C++.

Your function is too long. From its name, I predict what you really need is:

```
int int_sorter( const void *first_arg, const void *second_arg )
{
    return *(int*)first_arg - *(int*)second_arg;
}
```